# Maximum number of vowels in a word in string array

Tags: c++

I have written a program to input 2 strings in a string array.
And then print the maximum vowels stored in the list.
Where am i going wrong here,and is there a more elegant method to this.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
int i,j,c=0,k=0,maxo=0,len1,maxo1=0,len3;
char vow[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
char list[100][100],vow[]={"AEIOUaeiou"};
for(i=0;i<2;i++)  {
    cout<<"Enter word:  ";
    gets(list[i]);

    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        len1=strlen(list[i]);
        for(k=0;k<len1;k++) {
            for(j=0;list[j][k]!='\0';j++)
                if(list[j][k]==vow[j])
                    c++;
        }

        if(c>maxo)
            maxo=c;
        c=0;
    }

    cout<<"Maximum Vowel count:"<<maxo<<endl; 
}
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
  return 0;
  }
```

The bigger programme where i am trying to incorporate this code.The necessary comments are in the code.I really cannot undertand where i am going wrong in the last part.
Should i include the last bit of code at first so that the program works?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 int i,n,len=0,sum=0,j,max,min,c=0,c2=0,k=0,maxo=0,len1,maxi=0,c1=0,len2;
float avg;
char list[100][100] = { 0 };
char vow[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
for(i=0;i<2;i++) 
{
  cout<<"Enter word:  ";
  gets(list[i]);

  len=strlen(list[i]);                                
  sum=sum+len;
  cout<<"Length of word:  "<<len<<endl;
  if(list[i][len-1]=='s')
  {cout<<"The Word "<<list[i]<<" ends with s"<<endl;
   c2++;
  }

  }
  //Word input by user.Prints word along with length.       
  min=strlen(list[0]);
  max=strlen(list[0]);
  //Initialising max and min.
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    if(strlen(list[i])<min)
    {min=strlen(list[i]);}
    if(strlen(list[i])>max)
    {max=strlen(list[i]);}

  }
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
  if(max==strlen(list[i]))
  cout<<"The max value of the lengths stored:"<<list[i]<<endl<<"Word count:"<<max<<endl;               
  if(min==strlen(list[i]))
  cout<<"The min value of the lengths stored:"<<list[i]<<endl<<"Word count:"<<min<<endl;
  }
  //Max and Min value of string lengths are printed.
  avg=sum/2; 
  cout<<"Avg length:"<<avg<<endl;
  //Average value printed.
  cout<<"The number of words with s:"<<c2<<endl;
  //Word ending with s.


  {for (i = 0; i <2; i++) 

    len1 = strlen(list[i]);
    for (k = 0; k < len1; k++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(vow); j++)
            //if (list[j][k] == vow[j])
            if (list[i][k] == vow[j])
                c++;
    }
    cout << "Number of vowels in line " << i << ": " << c << '\n';
    if (c>maxo) maxo = c;
    c = 0;
    cout << "Maximum Vowel count so far:" << maxo << "\n\n";

     cout << "Maximum Vowel count:" << maxo << endl;
       }
for(i = 0 ;i < 2 ;i++)
{ len3 = strlen(list[i]);
letter = list[i][0];
{for(j=0;j<len3;j++)
if(list[i][j]==letter)
 counter++;

 }
 cout << "Number of identical letters as  first letter in line " << i << ": 
 " << counter << '\n';
 if (c>maxo1) maxo1 = counter;
 counter = 0;
 cout << "Maximum letter count so far:" << maxo1 << "\n\n";

 cout << "Maximum letter count:" << maxo1 << endl;
 }
```

PS:

*I have edited my code one more time to display the alphabet which has occurred the maximum number of times as starting letter of a word in the list,and the number of times it has occurred.*

Comment: Post a [MCVE]..

Comment: If your code works, then SO it not the right place for your question.

Comment: Can you tell me where i can post these things?

Comment: What makes you think that you are going wrong anywhere? Is it not behaving as expected? Did you do anything to find out more about the misbehaviour of your code? Can you provide some context code to demonstrate the misbehaviour? I.e. add a main(), feed sample input, provide the resulting output and compare it to the desired output.

Comment: Yes tried switch case and then came to know it does not work for strings

Comment: And this the exact code i tried to run but it is not working

Comment: It's better to put the code in a function, so you can call it from main with a known input that produces the wrong output. And say what the correct output is, too. If it is correct, but you want help making it better, post on stackreview.

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile for me for two reasons:

1) gets()

> The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively
>   removed this function from its specification. The function is
>   deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows C99+TC3).

And so I can't use the gets() function.

2) You can't declare

```
char list[100][100], char vow[] = {"AEIOUaeiou"};
```

both with a comma separator.

You read the input for the first line string into the first row of the array i = 0; then you instantly loop through i, which doesn't make sense. The following is not a good solution as in C++ you should be using std::vectors and std::string, and not generally mixing C and C++ but I've tried to keep it as close to your version, using my telepathic powers to read your mind about what you're trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int numLinesToGet = 10;
const int maxCharsPerLine = 100;

int main()
{
    int i, j, c = 0, k = 0, maxo = 0, len1;

    //char list[100][100], char vow[] = {"AEIOUaeiou"};
    char list[100][100] = { 0 };
    char vow[] = "AEIOUaeiou";

    //for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (i = 0; i < numLinesToGet; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Enter word:  ";
        std::cin.getline(list[i], maxCharsPerLine);
        //gets(list[i]);

        //for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) Get rid of this second loop entirely
        len1 = strlen(list[i]);
        for (k = 0; k < len1; k++) 
        {
            //for (j = 0; list[j][k] != '\0'; j++)
            for (j = 0; j < sizeof(vow); j++)
                //if (list[j][k] == vow[j])
                if (list[i][k] == vow[j])
                    c++;
        }
        cout << "Number of vowels in line " << i << ": " << c << '\n';
        if (c>maxo) maxo = c;
        c = 0;
        cout << "Maximum Vowel count so far:" << maxo << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "Maximum Vowel count:" << maxo << endl;

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Online example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ByZ0krWdz)

Comment: @starunique Oh dear, so many problems, avg = sum / 2; won't give the proper average because int / int always gives an int. 5 / 2 will give 2 for example. Also, the very last loop is broken because 

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) len1 = strlen(list[i]);

Only executes the first line after it, it doesn't execute any of the code after it in the loop. For it to do this you need to wrap ALL of the code you want in the loop in { } brackets. I understand your keenness to write this stuff, but really try make yourself a tea and start watching some youtube tutorials. C++ is quite tricky.

Comment: @@starunique Also, I don't know what compiler you're using, but every single problem or error you've come across would have been discovered by you if you just stepped through the code patiently and checked out some of the values and see where the execution jumps to.

Comment: can you suggest me a good c++ tutorial site in youtube i am a beginner and dont know how to go forward here.

Comment: And that avg part is intentional,I dont want to display length in fraction so thats that but thanx anyway.

Comment: @starunique Hmm, there are so many. Nearly everyone on this site will tell you to read a good C++ book, but there's no reason you can't learn from other sources. I think learning from video tutorials can be helpful especially if you follow the video by typing the code yourself.

Comment: And i really dont understand the broken loop thing there,where should i put the brackets.?Sorry to disturb this has eating my head off for the past few hours.

Comment: can you please have a look for the very last time.

Comment: @starunique2016 Did you even try compile this? Cause it won't. You have variables "counter", "maxo1", "len3", and "letter" declared nowhere in the code and are trying to use them. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: now done i actually forgot to add the variable in here,i did so on my computer program @Zerbrafish.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char a[] = "i love to code in education";
    int i, count = 0, vow = 0, mvow = 0;
    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
      {
        if (a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'i' || a[i] == 'o'
            || a[i] == 'u')
          {
            vow++;
          }
        if (a[i]==' ')
        {
          count++;
          mvow = vow;
          vow = 0;
        }
     }

printf ("Total words: %d\n", count+1);
if(vow>mvow) printf ("Max Vowels in a word: %d", vow);
else printf("Max Vowels in a word: %d", mvow);
  return 0;
}
```